# Problems with QT 5 deployment

Tags: qt

I've attempted to follow the instructions on deploying Qt to Windows, but I am stuck on step number 1.  In it, it tells you to:

cd C:\path\to\Qt
configure -static any other options you need

Unfortunately, I can't get the Qt DOS prompt to recognize the "configure" command despite attempting to use it in virtually every folder under my Qt installation.  Does anyone know where this command is store?  Everything else about my project is working great with Visual Studio, but I just can't seem to figure out the deployment.

I've Googled the crap out of this and tried both the Qt and the regular Windows command prompts.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

EDIT:  For clarity, I have tried dragging all of the .dlls needed to run my program (by running it and finding the ones I get errors on), but all that happens is I stop getting errors when trying to run my app.  If I double click it with the .dlls in the same folder, nothing happens at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you need the *static* Qt build? Note that you must static build the actual Qt framework for that, and only after that you can build your application.

If yes, make sure you have the Qt source code, because *configure* is part of the source code of Qt, it's a tool that configure the Qt build.

Comment: Oh, now I feel silly.  I didn't realize I needed to compile from source to be able to do that.  In fact, I don't think that was in the instructions I found online either.

Comment: Don't feel silly, i think that the deployment documentation is not really clear that for static deployment you need to build Qt yourself (and also if you use the open source version LGPL has some restrictions regarding static linkage)

Answer (score 0):

The step refers to path of Qt Source directory e.g. C:\QtSDK\QtSources\\ 
As you can see in qt5 [source tree](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt5/trees/stable) there is a file configure.bat
You need to run that with static option, so it will configure Qt for static linking.
Then you need to re-build Qt to make your new configuration to take effect.